# How to properly display an error when Commandline Argument is left blank by user?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, methods

So as you can I see i am reading from a file and displaying all the integers in the file and putting the amount in an array, What I need help with is just a trycatch block which prints out "You did not enter anything", Basically when the Commandline argument is left blank by the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Print5{

    public static void main(String[] commandlineArgument) {
        Integer[] array = Print5.readFileReturnIntegers(commandlineArgument[0]);
        Print5.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, commandlineArgument[0]);
    }

    public static Integer[] readFileReturnIntegers(String filename) {

        Integer[] temp = new Integer[10000];
        int i = 0;    
        File file = new File(filename);//Connects File
        Scanner inputFile = null;

        try{
            inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException Exception1) {
            System.out.println("File not found!"); //error message when mistyped 
        }


        //where the blank error arg will go
        if (inputFile != null) {

            try {
                while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        temp[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                        i++;
                    } catch (InputMismatchException Exception3) { //change this back to e if doesnt work
                        inputFile.next();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {
                inputFile.close();
            }

            Integer[] array = new Integer[i];
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, 0, i);
            return array;
        }
        return new Integer[] {};
    }

    //Prints the array 
    public static void printArrayAndIntegerCount(Integer[] array, String filename) {
        System.out.println("number of integers in file \"" + filename + "\" = " + array.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("index = " + i + "," + " element = " + array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need try catch block? can you check it with if condition in ur main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check on the size of the array and exit the program after displaying an error message:

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArgument) {
    if(commandlineArgument.length < 1) {
        System.err.println("Your error message"); // use the std error stream
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    ...
```

By convention, a nonzero status argument to `System.exit()` indicates abnormal termination.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the args array length:

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArgument) {

     if ( commandlineArgument.length > 0 ) {
         Integer[] array = Print5.readFileReturnIntegers(commandlineArgument[0]);
         Print5.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, commandlineArgument[0]);
     }
     else {
          System.out.println("usage - ... your message");
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Apache CLI library.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

It allows you to define required options and fail out if they're missing.